# Popover with 2 selects inside

Tags: angularjs, angular-bootstrap

I'm facing a bit off a problem with a uib-popover (angularJS).

Here is a code example of the main view:

```
<button class="btn btn-skeeled"
            uib-popover-template="'example.html'"
            popover-placement="left" popover-trigger="outsideClick">
    <i class="fa fa-external-link"></i>
</button>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="example.html">
    <custom-directive>
    </custom-directive>
</script>
```

Then, the custom-directive's view:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <select ng-model="selected.person"
            ng-options="person for person in availablePeople">
            <option value="">-- Select a person --</option>
        </select>
        <div ng-hide="!selected.person.hasLangs">
            <select ng-model="selected.personLang"
                ng-options="lang for lang in selected.person.langs">
                <option value="">-- Select a language --</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
<div>
    <button class="btn btn-thin"
            ng-click="doSomethingToSelectedPerson()">Send person
    </button>
</div>
```

Pretty simple and straigh-forward example I think.

What happens is: I select a person (first select), the second one appears and when you click on it the options are blank. If click outside and try to click again on the second select the options are properly displayed.

[Plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/AUxZwHPUXrzo6Zsio9RP?p=preview)

*Versions*:

- AngularJS - 1.4.0
- Bootstrap - 3.3.7
- Angular-Bootstrap - 1.1.2

I can tell that they are always there because I can inspect the scope and also because the dropdown size is correct.

For testing purposes, I have tested with having the selects all displayed (to eliminate the "hide" possibility) and also I tested using static data on the second select. The output is the same.

Which leads me to conclude that the problem is actually having more than one select inside a uib-popover.

[**EDIT**] Added plunker example

Comment: Are you able to reproduce it in Fiddle/Plunker? please post demo

Comment: Fair enough, I'll try!

Comment: I added the example... it's ugly but it shows the problem...